# How to convert a POJO to Map<String, AttributeValue> for dynamo db?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am using transaction for dynamodb. And transaction **Put** request takes  **com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item** as input param. So, I need to convert a **POJO** to a *Map*.

So far I have tried converting the object to string using Jackson and then converting the string to an item.
Below is the code I have tried.

```java
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonStr = null;
        try {
            jsonStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Item item = new Item().withJSON("document", jsonStr);
        Map<String,AttributeValue> attributes = ItemUtils.toAttributeValues(item);
    return attributes.get("document").getM();
```

Problem is, a field of 'Set' type returns 'List' after conversion.
Any suggestion how to overcome this?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432229

Comment: @MatthewPope, I have implemented the solution following your answer. But still the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should solve your convertion:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> valueMap = ItemUtils.toAttributeValues(item);
CustomEntity entity = dynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObject(CustomEntity.class, valueMap);
```